# Ci PHP send email with media not working in mobile browser

Tags: php, email, mobile, continuous-integration

Help me with may email sender: I use codeigniter like the bellow code:

```
      <code>
             $text = " <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html lang='en'>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
                <style>
                    #body {
                        font-size: 14px;
                    }
                    h1 {
                        color: blue !important;
                    }
                    .colored {
                        color: blue !important;
                    }
                    .hi { color: blue !important; }
                    #hiid  { color: blue !important; }

                    @media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
                        .colored {
                          color: red !important;
                        }
                        h1 {
                          color: red !important;
                        }
                        .hi { color: red !important; }
                        #hiid  { color: red !important; }
                    }
                    @media screen and (max-device-width: 767px), screen and (max-width: 767px) {
                        .colored {
                          color: blue !important;
                        }
                        h1 {
                          color: blue !important;
                        }
                        .hi { color: blue !important; }
                        #hiid  { color: blue !important; }
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id='body'>
                  <h1 class='hi' id='hiid' style='color: #ff00e0;'>Hi Pierce, ".$acak."</h1>
                  <p class='colored'>This text is blue if the window width is below 500px and red otherwise.</p>
                  <p>Jerry</p>
                </div>
            </body>
            </html>";


           $isi_email = $text;
           $config = array(
                'protocol'    => $this->config->item('protocol'),
                'smtp_host'   => $this->config->item('smtp_host'),
                'smtp_port'   => $this->config->item('smtp_port'),
                'smtp_user'   => $this->config->item('smtp_user'),
                'smtp_pass'   => $this->config->item('smtp_pass'),
                'smtp_crypto' => $this->config->item('smtp_crypto'),
                'mailtype'    => 'html'
            );

        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

        and another setting from/to email
        $this->email->message($isi_email);

        $email = $this->email->send();
</code>
```

and this result if I use desktop browser:
[on desktop browser work normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0RhP.png)

and this result if I check function media query, working good:
[on dekstop browser with media queri check work normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMwcz.png)

but if i check on mobile all styles are not inline and attribute (class/id) element is removed. 
[on mobile check view media queri not working jus style inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDJQ1.png)

i have check my console when open inbox and get this error, but i dont know why. please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ2zj.png)

Comment: becafull you got some javascript errors in your browser console, check it too

Comment: i have read and try code from this link  : https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css#css_media_queries

Comment: @Inazo i check my console when i open email in mobile version and i get this :
Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (2)